# apache windows xp not starting after installing new ssl certificate from godaddy

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, windows-xp

I am running apache 2.2 on windows. I currently have ssl running and have a key.pem file and a domain.crt file. THis was issued by godaddy.  Everything is working. I renewed the ssl cert and downloaded the file from godaddy and have 2 files a xyzzy.crt and a gd_bundle.crt. I tried configuring the server with those files. but got an error saying AH02245: Init: SSLPassPhraseDialog builtin is not supported on Win32 (key file C:/apache/cert.crt) when I try to start it up. I did some research and tried the openssl rsa -in cert.crt -out certout.crt, but it says that there is no private key in there. I know when I did the signing certificate, I did not do a passphrase key. I also found where it said to comment out the SSLPassPhraseDialog builtin directive in the httpd.conf file. I do not have it in there and do not have the ssl.cnf file linked. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated as I am a novice at this at best. 
Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out. I am posting this so it may help someone else out or maybe me in 2 years when I need to do this again. Not understanding how the whole ssl process worked, I went through and generated a signing certificate. I did not enter anything in for the passphrase which was ok. When I generated the newkey using openssl, I did not realize that this was the new key file. I thought that because I did not enter a passphrase, there was no key file, so I commented out the keyfile. Once I put that in with the generated keyfile, it worked and upon testing it with the godaddy testing tool, it was installed correctly. I obviously was not sure how everything needed to be installed and unfortuneltely, neither did godaddy.

Answer (score 0):

I have installed new **ssl** certificate from godaddy and faced the similar problem
"`SSLPassPhraseDialog builtin is not supported on Win32`"
I tried many things didn't work but it was rather easy fix. Just remove **PassPhrase** using following command `openssl rsa -in <filename1>.key -out <filename2>.key`
You will have to enter **PassPhrase** when you first generated `.key` file for certificate.